# Mocha error in Karma: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

Tags: mocha.js, karma-runner

My karma tests were working fine and now I'm getting this weird error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Restarting all karma sessions fixed this.